# Unable to set ComboBox.RowSource on continuous form

Tags: ms-access, vba, continuous-forms

I am having trouble setting the row source of a certain combo box on my form (viewed as a continuous form, although I also seem to have some problems in single-form mode).

The combo-box is bound to a field called `supplierID`, and is meant to present the user with a list of all the possible suppliers for an item.  The row-source I am using for the combo-box is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Suppliers.name, Suppliers.supplierID
FROM Suppliers
INNER JOIN PartsSuppliers ON Suppliers.supplierID=PartsSuppliers.supplierID 
WHERE PartsSuppliers.partID = partID;
```

When I view this query in the query designer (with a partID hard-coded), it works fine - it selects all the possible suppliers for the chosen item, and doesn't show any other items.  But when I look at the items in the combo-box, it shows *all* the suppliers present in the `PartsSuppliers` table (which has just two columns, mapping the parts to the possible suppliers for them).

I have also tried to set the combo-box's RowSource using some VBA in the OnFocus event (hardcoding the partID value in), but it never seems to change the RowSource.  The VBA code I am using is:

```
Private Sub supplierID_GotFocus()
    Dim query As String

    query = "SELECT DISTINCT Suppliers.name, PartsSuppliers.supplierID "
    query = query & "FROM Suppliers INNER JOIN PartsSuppliers ON Suppliers.supplierID = PartsSuppliers.supplierID "
    query = query & "WHERE (((PartsSuppliers.partID)=" & partID & "));"

    supplierDropDown.RowSource = query
    supplierDropDown.Requery
End Sub
```

I also tried opening that query in a RecordSet, and then using setting that RecordSet as the combo-box's RecordSet, but that didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong, or is there some other way that I should be looking at to make the correct drop down?

N.B. I have seen [Custom row source for combo box in continuous form in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86278/custom-row-source-for-combo-box-in-continuous-form-in-access), but that accepted solution didn't work for me either.

Comment: I'm against editable continuous forms, as outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86278/custom-row-source-for-combo-box-in-continuous-form-in-access/88772#88772

Comment: @David: Thanks for linking to that.  I used a continuous form because it made more sense - the user can see all the items that are going to be ordered, adjust the quantity for each item, then click a button to generate the order form.  But your answer has made me realise that I could also quite easily make a popup for editing the item, which I will probably look at implementing in the near future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `OnEnter` and `OnExit` events to change out your `RowSource`.

```
Private Sub supplierID_Enter()
    supplierDropDown.RowSource = _
        "SELECT DISTINCT Suppliers.name, PartsSuppliers.supplierID " & _
        "FROM Suppliers INNER JOIN PartsSuppliers ON Suppliers.supplierID = PartsSuppliers.supplierID " & _
        "WHERE PartsSuppliers.partID = " & partID & ";"
End Sub

Private Sub supplierID_Exit()
    supplierDropDown.RowSource = _
        "SELECT DISTINCT Suppliers.name, PartsSuppliers.supplierID " & _
        "FROM Suppliers INNER JOIN PartsSuppliers ON Suppliers.supplierID = PartsSuppliers.supplierID;"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great.  The only problem is that when another combo-box has the focus, and the row's supplierID is not in the drop-down list, the combo-box is blank.  Do you know of any way to fix this?

Comment: Yes, I knew you would notice that.  It is an unfortunate side effect that is caused by the filtering of the WHERE clause when you enter the combo.

Comment: It is by-design, in other words.

Comment: Well, I ended up using a combination of this and the method presented in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86278/custom-row-source-for-combo-box-in-continuous-form-in-access, and it works pretty good for me now.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with how to avoid the 'blanks' left behind in a datasheet once Combo items are restricted and couldn't find any straight forward option for a long time....until now!

Leaving all of the available options in the Combo box but adding a temporary validation rule, using OnCurrent, does the trick perfectly.

Hoping this prevents someone banging their head on the desk for as long as I have.