# Access continuous forms and comboboxes

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a continuous form with three comboboxes on it. Each one's recordsource is filtered based on the value in the preceding combobox. I am having a problem with the 2nd and subsequent records not referencing the values in their current record... they appear to be referencing the first records value. I have attached a picture to better illustrate the issue. My question is, how can I get the comboboxes on the 2nd and subsequent records to reference the value in their current record?

[image: screenshot]

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: I did find this interesting post... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86278/custom-row-source-for-combo-box-in-continuous-form-in-access

Comment: Has the record has reference number? or record id? are they do you want to change the record in previous record combo to what you changed?can you use use update recordset where record id is.... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are some limitations in Access I can't get around with just implementing it right outta the box.

[Custom row source for combo box in continuous form in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86278/custom-row-source-for-combo-box-in-continuous-form-in-access)

However, I refresh the form when evver I click on Control 2 or 3, it will refresh the rowsource for that control to use the value in the current record's Control1. That seems to be working!