# Hide items in Access 2007 combo box without also clearing the text for records that refer to the hidden items

Tags: ms-access, combobox

Say I have two tables in Access 2007:

```
Table 'Person:
  Id : Autonumber
  Name : Text
  IsActive : Yes/No

Table 'Note':
  Id : Autonumber
  PersonId : Number (foreign key, Person.Id)
  Note : Memo
```

I have a form that lists all entries in the Note table, and allows users to insert/update records.  The control for the Person field on the form is a combo box with

```
Control Source = PersonId
Row Source = SELECT Person.Name, Person.Id FROM Person;
Bound Column = 2
Column Count = 2
Column Widths = 3cm;0cm
```

Now I want to limit the combo box so it only allows active persons to be selected, but when I add a 'WHERE Person.IsActive' to the RowSource query, the combo box for all records which refer to inactive people show up blank.  I thought that setting the 'Limit To List' option to 'No' would fix this, but when I do Access forces me to change the displayed column so that the combo box now displays the Person ids rather than the Person names, which is not helpful.

Is there a good way to have the best of both worlds?  I want to be able to hide inactive people from the combo box list, but still have inactive people show up as the value for the combo box in records that were created while currently-inactive people were still active.

**Edit**: related question: [Custom row source for combo box in continuous form in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/q/86278/1030345)

Answer (score 1):

You can add code to the current event that either changes the row source according to whether the person is active or inactive or you can show a textbox and hide the combobox on the same criterion.

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/86278/1030345) fleshes out your solution a bit more, and was helpful to me.

Comment: @ralbatross Your comment implies that you are using continuous forms, that is a different thing altogether. For example, unbound controls and continuous forms just will not work.

Comment: Yes, I am using continuous forms.  And yes, I'm finding that unbound controls are causing issues.  I guess I jumped the gun marking this as the solution.  Sorry

Comment: You cannot use unbound controls with continuous forms. Is it possible for you to bind the control? You can then use conditional formatting to diable the control when the record is inactive. If I had a little more information, it might be possible to provide more details.

Comment: I can bind the combo box, yes, but I can't both bind it and limit its values.  If I do then the combo box no longer displays the value for records that use values that don't appear in the drop down list.

Comment: Is it essentail that the user should be able to edit the records in the continuous form? Would a pop-up for for editing suit?

Comment: A pop-up could work, but it would feel incongruous.  I may have to go the route of having a separate form for creating/editing vs viewing.

Comment: I created a form with two controls, a textbox to hold the value obtained by joining the table with the lookup and a combo that allows the user to change the value. This is a continuous form that works. The combo is disabled by conditional formatting when the row is inactive. Would this idea work for you?

Answer (score 1):

if you add the isactive column to the Row Source and display it so the user can see which people are active

Row Source = SELECT Person.Name, Person.id, Person.IsActive FROM Person

Column Count = 3

Column Widths = 3cm;0cm;1cm

then in the before update event of the combo box

```
Private Sub Combo10_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
If Not Me.Combo10.Column(2) Then
  MsgBox "You can only pick active people"
  Cancel = True
End If
```

Comment: Why give the user an opportunity to make an invalid choice, then tell them their choice is unacceptable?  Better to let them choose from only acceptable values, IMO.