# Control with conditional controlsource for each record in a report

Tags: ms-access, report

I'm having problem with my access report. I'm sorry if it looks trivial, but I'm quite new here...

I want a control to change it's source when it is empty. To exemplify (with a stripped down version of the problem), my report is based on a query which show the fields "id", "name" and "instution". If the "name" field is blank (empty), then "institution" is not.

I want a control in each row in the report to show "name" if it's not empty, and "institution" if "name" is empty.

I basically want a control to display a different information based on the value a field in my recordsource. But for each row.

I tried to use the "on current" event to set the controlsource or the value, but it won't really work, since anytime I click on a specific record, it change the value of for all record.

I basically understand the report to be continuous forms, and found some [similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86278/custom-row-source-for-combo-box-in-continuous-form-in-access), but the solutions didn't work for my case.

I thank you a lot for an answer, let me know if you need more info! Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a query and IIf.

```
 SELECT Id, IIf(Trim([Name] & "") = "", [Institution], [Name]) FROM ATable
```

Base the report on the query.

IIf: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/iif-function-HA001228853.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot, sometimes there too many ways to go somewhere and I find myself lost in the wrong one! I edited you post cause it's "IIf" and not "Iff"

Comment: Just one question about your code : why do you trim "& """ as well? Is that to prevent some kind of specific situation? An empty string is "", trimmed or not or am I wrong?

Comment: A null is not equal to "", but a null & "" is equal to "", so you cover nulls, zero-length strings and space-filled strings.